# content-script.js:95 Failed to get subsystem status for purpose

Tags: javascript, vite, solid-js

I see in console in chrome error: content-script.js:95 Failed to get subsystem status for purpose. I used solidjs, vite

I don't know how to solve it. I have this error on any project on Vitejs
I have this on any project on Vitejs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error probably related to browser addons, most likely React Dev Tools. Try running after disabling addons and exiting incognito mode if you are in it.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped, the ad blocker plugin was the cause. ;)\